# How to combine multiple except statements in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I'm catching 3 diffferent exceptions and the error is manipulated differently in all of them as below.

```
                except IntegrityError as e:
                    error_objects.append(
                        {
                            "Row Number": index + 1,
                            "Error": parse_integrity_error(e),
                            "data": user_given_data,
                        }
                    )
                except ValidationError as e:
                    error_objects.append(
                        {
                            "Row Number": index + 1,
                            "Error": e.detail[0],
                            "data": user_given_data,
                        }
                    )
                except Exception as e:
                    error_objects.append(
                        {
                            "Row Number": index + 1,
                            "Error": str(e),
                            "data": user_given_data,
                        }
                    )
```

Is there a clean/neat/pythonic way to do it?

Comment: Try changing the last element after inserting it with only row number and data

Comment: Honestly the way you're doing it is probably the most natural way. You *could* combine all the cases into the `except Exception` case with a later typecheck to figure out how to produce the `Error` value, but I think it's a lot clearer the way you have it now.

Comment: @Blckknght There are a lot of duplications in the OP's code so I wouldn't say it is the most natural way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would register exceptions in a function(or even a dictionary outside the function) like this(This is an example) :

```
def exception_return_value(e):
    type_e = type(e)

    if type_e == IndexError:
        error = 'IndexError Value'
    elif type_e == ValueError:
        error = 'ValueError Value'
    else:
        error = 'Exception Error'

    return {"Row Number": 10, "Error": error, "data": 20}


try:
    raise ValueError()

except (IndexError, ValueError, Exception) as e:
    return_value = exception_return_value(e)
    print(return_value)
```

Because I didn't have your code, I couldn't run it, but you can rewrite it like :

```
def exception_return_value(e):
    type_e = type(e)

    if type_e == IntegrityError:
        error = parse_integrity_error(e)
    elif type_e == ValidationError:
        error = e.detail[0]
    else:
        error = str(e)

    return {"Row Number": index + 1, "Error": error, "data": user_given_data}


try:
    ...
except (IntegrityError, ValidationError, Exception) as e:
    return_value = exception_return_value(e)
    error_objects.append(return_value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since all of your exception handlers do the same thing and differ only in how they convert an exception object to a string, you can add a `__str__` method to each of your custom exception classes (`IntegrityError` and `ValidationError` in your example) so that their instances can be formatted consistently with a call to the `str` function, just like how you convert a regular `Exception` object to string:

```
class IntegrityError(Exception):
    def __str__(self):
        return parse_integrity_error(self)

class ValidationError(Exception):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.detail[0]

try:
    ...
except Exception as e:
    error_objects.append(
        {
            "Row Number": index + 1,
            "Error": str(e),
            "data": user_given_data,
        }
    )
```